# Getting html control value using javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, function

I have this table in my page that I fetch by using AJAX request.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Example Name 1</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
                    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="deleteParticipantFunction()" class="delete-participant" value="2">
                        Delete
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Example Name 2</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
                    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="deleteParticipantFunction()" class="delete-participant" value="1">
                        Delete
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So I'm trying to get the anchor value when the button is clicked. So I make a function like this :

```
function deleteParticipantFunction(){
    var result = confirm('You are about to delete this participant. Continue?');
    if(result){
        var participant_id = $(this).val();
        console.log(participant_id);
    }
};
```

But I'm not able to get the value. What is the correct way to fetch the value in the function?

Comment: $(this).data('value') is going to take the value of data-value=""... if you need only value="" you just need $(this).val()

Comment: `value` attribute is not applied to `a` elements according to the w3 standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass id direct to method:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="deleteParticipantFunction(1)" class="delete-participant">
```

Then Yours js methods will be simpler:

```
function deleteParticipantFunction(participant_id){
var result = confirm('You are about to delete this participant. Continue?');
if(result){
    //delete smth by id
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Anchor elements don't *have* a `value` attribute.  That's something one finds on form inputs.  Instead, you can put the value in a `data-*` attribute:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="deleteParticipantFunction()" class="delete-participant" data-participant="1">
    Delete
</a>
```

And retrive it from the `data()` function:

```
var participant_id = $(this).data('participant');
```

Though, thinking about it, when calling the function like that, is `this` even the correct context?  I guess I haven't had to try that in a while so I don't know off the top of my head.  But fortunately you're already using jQuery, so why not just use jQuery?  Rather than put the function call on every element in an `onclick` attribute, use jQuery to bind a function to the click event(s):

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="delete-participant" data-participant="1">
    Delete
</a>
```

and:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-participant.', function () {
    var result = confirm('You are about to delete this participant. Continue?');
    if(result){
        var participant_id = $(this).data('participant');
        console.log(participant_id);
    }
});
```

Which has the added benefit of de-cluttering your markup.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function deleteParticipantFunction(e){
    var result = confirm('You are about to delete this participant. Continue?');
    if(result){
        var participant_id = this;
        console.log(e.value);
        //e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.remove()
    }
};
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Example Name 1</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
                    <button href="javascript:;" onclick="deleteParticipantFunction(this)" class="delete-participant" value="2">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Example Name 2</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
                    <button href="javascript:;" onclick="deleteParticipantFunction(this)" class="delete-participant" value="1">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```